# Haskell - Problem with non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching

I have the following haskell code:

Why doesn't *x1*'s pattern matching to function *f*?

Comment: Your pattern matches only lists with exactly 3 elements; it's the same as `[[_], (x,[xs]), [y,ys]]`. `x1` contains 4 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hard to read as-is. Let's use some creative whitespace to line things up.

```
f   ( [_        ]:[(x,[xs ])]:[y        ,ys       ]   :[]) = 1
x1 = [[(1,[1,2])],[(1,[1,2])],[(1,[1,2]),(1,[1,2])],[]]
```

Okay. So there's actually a couple different things that aren't going as you expect!

- `[xs]` does not match `[1, 2]`, because `[xs]` is a one-element list and `[1, 2]` is a two-element list (possible fix: `xs` instead of `[xs]`)
- `[y, ys]` happens to match, but I *suspect* not in the way you intended: `y` matches to the first element of the list, just as I think you intend, but *ys* to the second *element* of the list, not the remainder of the list I think you intend (possible fix: `(y:ys)` instead of `[y, ys]`)
- your pattern's `:[]` matches the closing bracket of a list definition, not a final `[]` element (possible fix: `:[]:[]` instead of `:[]`; the first `[]` there matches the element, and the second `[]` matches the end-of-list marker)

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now :)