# Haskell - A problem with non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have the following haskell code:

Why doesn't *x0*'s pattern matching to function *f*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell - Problem with non-exhaustive patterns in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528001/haskell-problem-with-non-exhaustive-patterns-in-function)

Comment: Given how similar this question and your last one are, I think it may be time to turn to the pattern-matching section of your favorite tutorial and review it more carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` and `ys` are two elements of the list. This thus means that the pattern:

`(x,xs) : [y, ys]` is short for `(x, xs) : y : ys : []`. The list thus contains *three* items: as first item a 2-tuple `(x, xs)` as second item `y` and as third item `ys`.

You can thus match this with:

```
--      ↓      ↓        ↓ three items in the sublist
[   [(1,[1]),(1,[1]), (1,[1])]]
```

or you should match this with:

```
f :: [[(a, [b])]] -> Int
f (((x, xs) : _) : y : _) = 0
```